# client script working without query string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

this client script working without query string with query string it does not show

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('POSTED SUCCESSFULLY');document.location.href='/Group.aspx?grp_id='"+ Group_ID.Value +"'&grp_name='"+ Group_Name.Value +"'';", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your code will output js code that looks similar to this:

```
alert('POSTED SUCCESSFULLY');document.location.href='/Group.aspx?grp_id='1'&grp_name='yourgroupname'';
```

There's some syntax errors in there. Change it to be without unnecessary the single quotes and [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) the values of `Group_ID` and `Group_Name` so they are url-friendly (might not be necessary, but I'd recommend it):

```
"alert('POSTED SUCCESSFULLY');document.location.href='/Group.aspx?grp_id="+ HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(Group_ID.Value) +"&grp_name="+ HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(Group_Name.Value) +"';"
```